# How to change System locale in Windows 7 using Command prompt

Tags: setlocale

Earlier in Windows XP, Our projects Uses the following code to change the system locale in Windows XP.

```
driveStr.Format("RUNDLL32.EXE SETUPAPI.DLL,InstallHinfSection %.8x 128 %s\\inf\\intl.inf", lgid, getenv("windir"));
```

Now we migrated the project to Windows 7, Whenever we try to change the language using above format, Application crashes. Later figured it out that  the file  `Intl.inf` which used in Windows XP is not part of the Windows 7 anymore which causes the application to crash.

Please let me know, Is there any way to change the system locale  on Windows 7 using Command prompt